# Реализация REST, одна функция или две, помогите выбрать из предложенных вариантов

Tags: python, flask, rest

Я бьюсь в двух углах над выбором как мне делать REST api
Пишу на Python+Flask+MongoDB

Вариант 1

```
@app.route("/api/settings/", methods=["POST"])
def метод1:
    выполнение куска кода.

@app.route("/api/setup/", methods=["POST"])
def метод2:
    выполнение куска кода.
```

Вариант 2

```
@app.route("/api/<method>", methods=["POST"])
def метод3(method):
    if method == "settings":
        выполнение куска кода
    elif method == "setup":
        выполнение куска кода
```

Помогите определиться что выбрать, и почему стоит выбрать тот или иной вариант?

Comment: код в вопросе, использует неправильный синтакс для Питона.

Answer (score 1):

В разных случаях можно использовать оба варианта. Предпочтение определяется абсолютно также как и для любых других функций в Питоне -- иначе говоря ваш вопрос эквивалентен: *в каких случаях нужно объединить две функции в одну или наоборот в каких случаях следует разбить одну функцию на две.*

Как обычно, желательно иметь high cohesion для кода внутри одной функции и loose coupling для кода из разных функций. Вопрос слишком общий для Stack Overflow. Для ответа больше подходит объём книги, например: Code Complete (Steve McConnell).